# Comparing the mean to the standard deviation

Tags: probability, reference-request

Let $X_1,X_2, \ldots ,X_n$ be i.i.d. random variables  with normal distribution
${\cal N}(\mu,\sigma)$. Let

$$
M=\frac{X_1+X_2+ \ldots +X_n}{n}, \ 
D=\sqrt{\sum_{k=1}^n (X_k-M)^2},\
Y=\frac{X_1+X_2+ \ldots +X_n}{D}
$$

I have two related questions about those variables :

(1) Is it true that $M$ and $D$ are independent ?

(2) Is the distribution of $Y$ known ?

Those questions may be stupid as I don’t know much about probability.

Comment: You should read about student's t-distributions.

Comment: (1) is true. It is a consequence of Cochran's theorem.

Comment: @Eckhard : indeed. I found all I needed on the wikipedia page on the Student distribution. Many thanks.